# No entiendo consulta mysql wordpress con sprintf php

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

alguien me puede ayudar a entender esta consulta mysql, no se ni para que sirve sprintf ni porque esta consulta se hace de esta forma tan rara

```
        $query = sprintf(
          'SELECT R.is_anonymous FROM `%1$sasq_results` R ',
          $this->db->prefix
        );

        $items = $this->db->get_results( $query);
```

solo se que la tabla a la cual hace referencia el select es una llamada 'asq_results', de resto no entiendo ni papa, gracias por su ayuda

Comment: No es una "forma rara" de hacer la consulta, [`sprintf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sprintf.php) es una función para formatear cadenas y, en tu caso, lo único que se hace es agregar un prefijo antes del nombre de tabla.

Comment: Excelente @Triby, al final pude entenderlo gracias a este blog, dejo aquí el enlace por si alguien mas tiene esta duda en el futuro
https://bykrailler.wordpress.com/2013/01/17/hacer-consultas-mysql-seguras-contra-sql-injection/

Comment: Esa es la forma de escribir las **consultas preparadas* en WordPress, [como explica la documentación](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/)